# Reclaim disk space after removing file from Docker container

Tags: docker

I've successfully copied a large database backup file (35 GB) into the Docker container and restored my database locally (following [this walkthrough](https://database.guide/how-to-restore-a-sql-server-database-on-a-mac-using-sql-operations-studio/)). I want to now delete that .bak file from the Docker container to reclaim the space. I did that by running `sudo docker exec sql_server rm -rf /var/opt/mssql/backup/example.bak` but this didn’t reclaim the space - my Docker.raw file remains about 76 GB. When I run `docker system df` it says my containers are 45 GB though. I tried `docker system prune -a` but this reclaimed 0B. Restarting Docker didn't do the trick. How do I shrink that now that the file is removed in order to gain that space back?

Answer (score 3):

> I did that by running `sudo docker exec sql_server rm -rf /var/opt/mssql/backup/example.bak` but this didn’t reclaim the space

Whether this will free up space depends on whether the file exists only in the container or if it exists in your image. Once a file exists in the image, deleting it in the container doesn't modify the image itself. Instead only the container filesystem is updated with an indication that the file is deleted from the view of that container. This is how the layered filesystem works under the covers.

> When I run `docker system df` it says my containers are 45 GB though

You can examine this a bit deeper. For any specific container, you can run a `docker container diff` command on the container id to see the files that have been modified inside that container.

> I tried `docker system prune -a` but this reclaimed 0B.

This will not reclaim space from a running container. If the container is stopped, it will be deleted, and the image that started that container may also be deleted if nothing else points to it. Otherwise docker will avoid running containers and there's no pruning it can run on the files inside a running container.

> my Docker.raw file remains about 76 GB

This is a very key point, it suggests that you are running Docker on a Mac. All of the above steps may reduce disk space of the Linux environment that Docker runs on top of. However, the VM that Docker uses on Mac and Windows is mapped to a file that grows on demand as the VM needs it. From the [Docker for Mac FAQ](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/faqs/#dockerraw-consumes-an-insane-amount-of-disk-space), diskspace reported by this file may not be accurate because of sparse files work on Mac:

> **Docker.raw consumes an insane amount of disk space!**
>
> This is an illusion. Docker uses the raw format on Macs running the
>   Apple Filesystem (APFS). APFS supports sparse files, which compress
>   long runs of zeroes representing unused space. The output of ls is
>   misleading, because it lists the logical size of the file rather than
>   its physical size. To see the physical size, add the -ks switch; to
>   see the logical size in human readable form, add -lh:
>
> ```
> $ cd ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0
> $ ls -klsh Docker.raw
> 2333548 -rw-r--r--@ 1 akim  staff    64G Dec 13 17:42  Docker.raw
> ```
>
> In this listing, the logical size is 64GB, but the physical size is
>   only 2.3GB.
>
> Alternatively, you may use du (disk usage):
>
> ```
> $ du -h Docker.raw
> 2,2G  Docker.raw
> ```

I'd also recommend looking at how much disk space is used inside the Docker VM with:

```
sudo docker run --rm -v /var/lib/docker:/host/var/lib/docker:ro \
  busybox df -h /host/var/lib/docker
```

Comment: Interesting. Indeed am using Docker for Mac. My logical size is 87.5 GB, physical is 71 GB. I expected physical to be much closer to 35 GB. That last command gives size of 87.5G, used 45.6G, 37.4G available. Is there a way to shrink the physical disc space from 71 to the 46 GB used?

Comment: I haven't seen anything to further compress this file. The underlying filesystem may have created files spread across multiple sectors. But more than likely, the sectors aren't zeroed out when the file is deleted. And until they are zeroed, the raw format can't free up the sectors. If you really need that disk space, you may need to destroy and recreate the file, which would be the equivalent of a reinstall of docker.

Comment: Do you think the information Ortomala Lokni posted would cause that to shrink?

Comment: @Joey I typically recommend against squashing layers. It could shrink one image, but you then can't reuse layers if you rebuild the image, resulting in disk usage doubling on the next build. Those changes will only affect disk usage inside the VM. And since you created the file with an exec rather than a build, it never made it into the read-only layers, so squashing won't give you any savings.

Comment: I relayed this question to [a related github issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2297#issuecomment-409386123). That may get the attention of someone that can give you a better option than wipe and replace.

Comment: I wondered if resizing the disk to 48 GB instead of 96 would do the trick but this doesn't sound like what I want: Resizing to a smaller size will delete the disk image; all Docker images / containers will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [article](https://tuhrig.de/flatten-a-docker-container-or-image/), you can flatten a container with:

```
# export the container to a tarball
docker export <CONTAINER ID> > /home/export.tar

# import it back
cat /home/export.tar | docker import - some-name:latest
```

[`docker export`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/) exports the container’s filesystem as a tar archive and [`docker import`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/import/) imports the contents from a tarball to create a filesystem image.

You can avoid using a temporary file by piping directly from [`docker export`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/) to [`docker import`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/import/) with:

```
docker export <CONTAINER ID> | docker import - flatten-container:latest
```

Comment: Interesting, can you explain what this does? Is `some-name` the name of the container, what is `latest`? Does this essentially overwrite the filesystem of the existing container? I assume creating that export.tar will require another 35 GB free space, but the import potentially may not?

Comment: @Joey I've updated my answer. `some-name` is the name of the container, `latest` is the tag of the container. And you don't need a 35 GB temporary file, if you pipe directly from `docker export` to `docker import`.